# FormRequest errors returns array with wrong array keys

Tags: laravel-5.6

First time i run into this problem, never had it before. I've got the following FormRequest class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ValidateForm extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
    ];
}
}
```

When validation fails, after redirect the `$errors` object returns the following:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => The name field is required.
)
```

The array key is numeric, so i can't use `$errors->has('name')` , does anyone know what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: are you passing `name` or `name[]` from view

Comment: Im using this formfield: `{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`